# How can restrict certain users from delete a category but can view only in wordpress?

Tags: capabilities

I would like to remove the capability of 'delete_term' for certain users.  If can find the code which shows the 'delete' from 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php' line number so where around 480...

Comment: You could use a role manager plugin that takes away this permission from those users.

Comment: You should never modify files in `wp-admin` or `wp-includes`, all those changes will be deleted when WP updates. You should be using actions and filters to modify core behaviour

Comment: I do not want to use plugins.... how can I deny_to (user_role) and caps_for ( ['delete_term']).... which is not working for me.